# Elasticsearch 5.1 and Docker - How to get networking configured properly to reach Elasticsearch from the host

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

Using Elasticsearch:latest (v5.1) from the Docker public repo, I created my own image containing Cerebro. I am now attempting to get Elasticsearch networking properly configured so that I can connect to Elasticsearch from Cerebro. Cerebro running inside of the container I created, renders properly on my host at: http://localhost:9000.

After committing my image, I created my Docker container with the following:

```
sudo docker run -d -it --privileged --name es5.1 --restart=always \
-p 9200:9200 \
-p 9300:9300 \
-p 9000:9000 \
-v ~/elasticsearch/5.1/config:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config \
-v ~/elasticsearch/5.1/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data \
-v ~/elasticsearch/5.1/cerebro/conf:/root/cerebro-0.4.2/conf \
elasticsearch_cerebro:5.1 \
/root/cerebro-0.4.2/bin/cerebro
```

my elasticsearch.yml in ~/elasticsearch/5.1/config currently has the following network and discovery entries specified:

```
network.publish_host: 192.168.1.26
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.168.1.26:9300"]
```

I have also tried 0.0.0.0 and not specifying the values to default to the loopback for these settings. In addition, I've tried specifying network.host with a combination of values. No matter how I set this, elasticsearch logs on startup:

```
[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Prod)
[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Cannot invoke the action
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:9200
… cascading errors because of this connection refusal...
```

No matter how I set the elasticsearch.yml networking, the error message on Elasticsearch startup does not change. I verified that the elasticsearch.yml is being picked-up inside of the Docker container. Please let me know were I'm going wrong with this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like I"m answering my own question after a days-worth of battle with this! The issue was that elasticsearch wasn't started inside of the container. To determine this, I got a terminal into the container:

```
docker exec -it es5.1 bash
```

Once in the container, I checked service status:

```
service elasticsearch status
```

To this, the OS responded with:

[FAIL] elasticsearch is not running ... failed!

I started it with:

```
service elasticsearch start
```

I add a single script that I'll call from docker run to start elasticsearch and cerebro and that should do the trick. However, I would still like to hear if there is a better way to configure this.

Comment: You definitely don't want services running in the Docker container. You really want the Elasticsearch process running in the foregraound as the sole process. Services and cron jobs don't get run inside the container.

Comment: Thanks. I think you've hit on the issue, that I'm trying to run ES as a service in a container.

Answer (score 0):

I made a github docker-compose repo that will spin up a elasticsearch, kibana, logstash, cerebro cluster

https://github.com/Shuliyey/elkc

========================================================================

On the other hand, in regard to the actual problem (elasticsearch_cerebro not working).

To get the elasticsearch and cerebro working in one docker container. Need to use supervisor

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/

will update with more details

Comment: Thank you, Shuliyey! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use supervisor at all. A very simple way to solve this is to use docker-compose and bundle Elasticsearch and Cerebro together, like this:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    build: elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
      - ./elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx1500m -Xms1500m"
    networks:
      - elk

  cerebro:
    build: cerebro
    volumes:
      - ./cerebro/config/application.conf:/opt/cerebro/conf/application.conf
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge
```

elasticsearch/Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.1
```

cerebro/Dockerfile:

```
FROM yannart/cerebro
```

Then you run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`. When everything is started, you can access ES at http://localhost:9200 and Cerebro at http://localhost:9000