# How to access an Elasticsearch stored in a Docker container from outside?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, networking, containers

I'm currently runnning Elasticsearch (ES) 5.5 inside a Docker container. (See below)

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'
{
  "name" : "THbbezM",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "CtYdgNUzQrS5YRTRT7xNJw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.5.0",
    "build_hash" : "260387d",
    "build_date" : "2017-06-30T23:16:05.735Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I've changed the elasticsearch.yml file to look like this:

```
http.host: 0.0.0.0

# Uncomment the following lines for a production cluster deployment
#transport.host: 0.0.0.0
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
```

I can currently get my indexes through curl -XGET commands. The thing here is that I wanted to be able to do http requests to this ES instance using it's Ip Address instead of the 'localhost:9200' setting starting from my machine (Mac OS X).

So, what I've tried already:

1) I've tried doing it in Postman getting the following response:

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to X.X.X.X:9200/.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Client certificates are required for this server:
Fix this by adding client certificates in Settings > Certificates
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

2) I also tried in Sense (Plugin for Chrome):

```
Request failed to get to the server (status code: 0):
```

3) Running a curl from my machine's terminal won't do it too.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you are using docker on a Mac, docker creates a linux VM in the background and runs the containers inside this VM. You need to get the IP of the VM and enable port forwarding to your container.

Comment: @yamenK I'm using the IP of the VM that Docker creates. Still not working anyway. I've checked it using docker -inspect <container_name>

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752646/elasticsearch-5-1-and-docker-how-to-get-networking-configured-properly-to-reac/45549124#45549124

Comment: The docker container IP that shows using the inspect command is not the same as the VM IP. Containers have a private virtual network.

Comment: Can you help me identify where can I get that ip address for the VM? Not quite getting there yet ...

Answer (score 2):

Docker for Mac provides a DNS name you can use:

`docker.for.mac.localhost`

Comment: Should I use that DNS name in the elasticsearch.yml when specifying the binded host?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the value specified under container name in the YML file to connect to your cluster. Example:

```
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: 'example_elasticsearch'
    image: 'docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.1'
```

In this case, elastic search is located at  http://example_elasticsearch:9200. Note that `example_elasticsearch` is the name of the container and may be used the same way as machine name or host name.